# Multiprocessing is not working with python default IDE?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

My python default IDE is not working with multiprocessing:
code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Lock
import multiprocessing

def name1(i):
    print i

if __name__=="__main__":
    for i in range(5):
        process=multiprocessing.Process(target=name1,args=(i,))
        process.start()
```

But it works correctly and gives perfect output with eclipse
output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

But I don't get any error and output with python default IDLE it just restarts.

Comment: And what is your Python default IDE?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/ the problem is with version python 2.7.10. I don't get any output and error

Comment: do you mean from the python shell?

Comment: Maybe he means IDLE.

Comment: thanks for the info. Please help me with that if you can.

Comment: @Kevin, I think you are right, in that case Vajja it won't be happening, you cannot use multiprocessing with idle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why multiprocessing does not work in python Idle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678692/why-multiprocessing-does-not-work-in-python-idle)